# Smoothness-and-decay relationship of the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

Recall that a function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is said to be *rapidly decreasing* if
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \big|x^k f(x)\big| < \infty \quad \text{for all} \quad k = 0, 1, 2\dotsc$$

In the textbook [1, Lesson 19] I find the following statement:

> If $f \in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is rapidly decreasing, the same is true for $\widehat{f}$.

Is this really true? If every derivative of $f$ also have rapid decay, then the result follows from the invariance of the Fourier transform on the Schwartz space $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$, but this is not assumed here.

The most general results I know of are the following:

- **Proposition 1.** The Fourier transform of a rapidly decreasing, locally integrable function ${f \in \mathrm{L}_{\mathrm{loc}}^{1}(\mathbb{R})}$ is in $\mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. In particular, if $f \in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is rapidly decreasing, then ${\widehat{f} \in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})}$.
- **Proposition 2.** Suppose that ${f \in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \cap \mathrm{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})}$ with all its derivatives ${f^{(k)}}$ in ${\mathrm{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})}$ for ${k \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then the Fourier transform ${\widehat{f}}$ decays rapidly.

Rapid decay of the derivatives of $f$ would imply integrability of the derivatives, and hence that ${\widehat{f}}$ decays rapidly.

---

Source:

[1] C. Gasquet. P. Witomski. Fourier Analysis and Applications. Filtering, Numerical Computation, Wavelets.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the definition of "rapidly decreasing"? If it were the same as being a Schwartz test function...

Comment: I am looking at Lesson 19 in that book right now. I don't see the statement you are referring to. Can you give the page and line?

Comment: @UmbertoP. see paragraph below "19.1.4 Proposition" on page 172.